# Long running RxJava Subscriptions with refreshable data

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm looking to set up a long running data subscription to a particular data object in Android/RxJava. Specifically a combination of a Retrofit REST call paired with cached data. I've done this pretty simply just wrapping an API call with data, were the API call is Retrofit returning an Observable:

```
class OpenWeather {
    ...
    Observable<CurrentWeather> OpenWeather.getLocalWeather()
    ...
}
```

The simple implementation would be:

```
public static Observable<CurrentWeather> getWeatherOnce() {
    if (currentWeather != null)
        return Observable.just(currentWeather);
    return OpenWeather.getLocalWeather()
        .map(weather -> currentWeather = weather);
}
private static CurrentWeather currentWeather;
```

The problem is that there is no way to notify when the "current weather" has been updated. The simplest way to add refreshable data with long running updates between subscriptions would be to use a BehaviorSubject like such:

```
public class DataModel {

    public enum DataState {
        ANY,        // whatever is available, don't require absolute newest
        LATEST,     // needs to be the latest and anything new
    }

    private final static BehaviorSubject<CurrentWeather> currentWeatherSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();

    public static Observable<CurrentWeather> getCurrentWeather(DataState state) {
        synchronized (currentWeatherSubject) {
            if (state == DataState.LATEST || currentWeatherSubject.getValue() == null) {
                OpenWeather.getLocalWeather()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .toSingle()
                    .subscribe(new SingleSubscriber<CurrentWeather>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(CurrentWeather currentWeather) {
                            currentWeatherSubject.onNext(currentWeather);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable error) {
                            // ?? currentWeatherSubject.onError(error);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
        return currentWeatherSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Using the BehaviorSubject, when getting the current weather, get either the last cached entry and any updates as they occur. Thoughts?

So I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here as there seems there should be an easier way or more elegant way.

Comment: Thing is, who determines when the weather should get updated?

Comment: Weather was just a public API I'm writing samples against, in my world it is periodic or when push notifications are received, any subscribers should get notified of changes.